# Configure PyCharm Debugger to Display Array/Tensor Shape?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When I'm debugging with PyCharm, I'd like for the debugger to display the **shapes** of my NumPy arrays / Jax arrays / PyTorch Tensors. Instead, I see their values:

[image]

Is there a way to configure PyCharm's debugger so that the shapes of these multi-dimensional arrays is displayed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I achieve this by hacking member function `torch.Tensor.__repr__`, because PyCharm debugger calls `__repr__` to get string representation of the object.

```py
import torch

old_repr = torch.Tensor.__repr__
def tensor_info(tensor):
    return repr(tensor.shape)[6:] + ' ' + repr(tensor.dtype)[6:] + '@' + str(tensor.device) + '\n' + old_repr(tensor)
torch.Tensor.__repr__ = tensor_info
```

In PyCharm debugger, you will see representation like:

```py
>>>print(torch.ones(3,3))
Size([3, 3]) float32@cpu
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Snapshot of my variable inspector:
[image: PyCharm Debugger]

Comment: this doesn't work when the tensor is large. I see a lot of "..." in the representation

Answer (score 0):

Debugger just shows the objects in memory. So if you create an object representing shape, you should see it in the debugger.

For example, for numpy it's `numpy.array().shape`

Comment: Debugger doesn't just show objects in memory; it chooses which attributes to display alongside the objects. I want to change the default attribute displayed so that `np.array().shape` is displayed next to the object without needing to "open" the object in the debugger console

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately there's no such feature in PyCharm, so feel free to submit a feature request to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Check out Li Qimai's answer above ^^ :D